# Arcpy CopyFeatures creates empty shapefile

Tags: arcpy, features, copy

I'm running a script to create a buffer and find features from another shapefile that fall completely within that buffer. The script seems to work fine, it finds all the correct features (I checked using intersect in Desktop ArcMap) but then creates an empty shapefile. The resulting shapefile has the right schema from the input shapefile but no features.

EDIT: Strangely it seems to work fine if I do it to a GDB instead of a shapefile.

```
# this program buffers a file and finds what features are inside that buffer

# everything works except for writing to the new shapefile, and i can't figure out why

# import all the goodies
import ogr
import gdalconst
import sys
import os
import arcpy

# set the workspace for arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/work/lab8"

# set folders and files
folder = 'C:\\work\\lab8\\'
myFile = 'Parcels.shp'
myFile2 = 'Powerline.shp'
filename = folder + myFile

# get all the attributes using describe and count the number of features
desc = arcpy.Describe(myFile)
cm = arcpy.GetCount_management(myFile) 
nFeatures =int(cm[0])
print 'featureclass',myFile,'has',nFeatures,'features'
print 'running tool'

# make the new layers to select from
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(myFile, "parcels_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(myFile2, "powerline_lyr")

# set the buffer destination
buffer_file = 'powerline_buffer.shp'
buffer_output = folder+buffer_file

# if the layer exists, delete it
if arcpy.Exists(buffer_output):
    arcpy.Delete_management(buffer_output)

#create the buffer
bufferDist = 250
sideType = "FULL"
endType = "ROUND"
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("powerline_lyr", buffer_output, bufferDist, sideType, endType)

# make the buffer result a layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buffer_output, "buffer_lyr")

# run the intersect
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('parcels_lyr', 'COMPLETELY_WITHIN', 'buffer_lyr', "", "NEW_SELECTION")

# see how many features intersect. if 0, quit
matchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('parcels_lyr')[0]) 
if matchcount == 0:
    print('no features intersect')
    sys.exit()
else:
    print matchcount, 'intersected'

# Set output file name
out_name = "parcels_within.shp"
out_location = folder+out_name
print out_location

# if the new featureclass exists, delete it
# i took this out in case it was causing problems, but it doesn't seem to be the cause
if arcpy.Exists(out_location):
    arcpy.Delete_management(out_location)
    print 'bye'

# showing all the features that interserct, to make sure it works
print '\nThese features of',myFile, 'intersect the buffer of',myFile2,': \n'
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor('parcels_lyr')
for row in cursor:
    if row.getValue('SITUSADDR'):
        print row.getValue('SITUSADDR')

# Write the selected features to a new featureclass
# for some reason this creates an empty shapefile and I can't figure out why
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('parcels_lyr',  out_location)
```

Comment: Strangely it seems to work fine if I do it to a GDB instead of a shapefile.

Comment: That would seem to be important information for you to include in your question via using the [edit] button.  Don't forget that posting a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) rather than your full code is more likely to result in attracting a potential answerer sooner.

Comment: Will do. That is my full code

Comment: Oh, I see. I've seen other posts where commenters ask for the whole code so that's what I did here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a go at changing a few things in your code.

1. The way you've constructed file paths. Using os.path.join is a cleaner way to join paths, rather than folder + file method.
2. Using the raw file path method to identify paths. ie. when setting workspace or folder.
3. I usually try and use variables when constructing code.
4. I've set the workspace overwrite to True... This will overwrite the pre-created shapefile before adding the selection data to it.
5. Ive added the "da" version of searchcursor. I assume "SITUSADDR" is a field within the table, therefore you are searching against this for values.

   ```
   # set the workspace for arcpy 
   folder = arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:/work/lab8"
   arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

   # set folders and files
   myFile = os.path.join(folder, 'Parcels.shp')
   myFile2 = os.path.join(folder, 'Powerline.shp')

   # get all the attributes using describe and count the number of features
   desc = arcpy.Describe(myFile)
   cm = arcpy.GetCount_management(myFile) 
   nFeatures =int(cm[0])
   print 'featureclass',myFile,'has',nFeatures,'features'
   print 'running tool'

   # make the new layers to select from
   parcels_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(myFile, "parcels_lyr")
   powerline_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(myFile2, "powerline_lyr")

   # set the buffer destination
   buffer_file = 'powerline_buffer.shp'
   buffer_output = os.path.join(folder, buffer_file)

   # if the layer exists, delete it
   if arcpy.Exists(buffer_output):
       arcpy.Delete_management(buffer_output)

   #create the buffer
   bufferDist = 250
   sideType = "FULL"
   endType = "ROUND"
   arcpy.Buffer_analysis(powerline_layer, buffer_output, bufferDist, sideType, endType)

   # make the buffer result a layer
   buffer_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buffer_output, "buffer_lyr")

   # run the intersect
   selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(parcel_layer, 'COMPLETELY_WITHIN', buffer_layer, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

   # see how many features intersect. if 0, quit
   matchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(selection)[0]) 
   if matchcount == 0:
       print('no features intersect')
       sys.exit()
   else:
       print matchcount, 'intersected'

   # Set output file name
   out_name = "parcels_within.shp"
   out_location = os.path.join(folder, out_name)
   print out_location

   # if the new featureclass exists, delete it
   # i took this out in case it was causing problems, but it doesn't seem to be the cause
   if arcpy.Exists(out_location):
       arcpy.Delete_management(out_location)
       print 'bye'

   # showing all the features that interserct, to make sure it works
   print '\nThese features of',myFile, 'intersect the buffer of',myFile2,': \n'
   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selection, ['SITUSADDR']) as scursor:
       for srow in scursor:
           print srow[0]


   # Write the selected features to a new featureclass
   # for some reason this creates an empty shapefile and I can't figure out why
   arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(selection,  out_location)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. it gave me a syntax error on this line 'cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selection, ['SITUSADDR']) as scursor:

Comment: `cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selection, ['SITUSADDR']) as scursor:`

Comment: ive changed it. it should have been "with". Check the above code for the change

Comment: Thanks. That still runs fine but the .shp is still empty. If I do it to a GDB instead that works fine, oddly.

Comment: That is strange. I don't understand why that's happening. When you write to a GDB, are there any features?

Comment: Does your output need to be a SHP? If so, might be worth copying to GDB, then out to SHP.

Comment: Yes, that works just fine. A friend was doing the same thing and thought it might have something do to with the XY domain?

Comment: Sorry, I meant writing to the GDB works fine, but SHP doesn't no matter what I try.

Comment: Try and export to GDB, then back out to SHP. I'll add an interim GDB, add the data, export to SHP, then delete the GDB.